# create new domain for application on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, dns

we have create new application on k8s, this application is exposing nodePort service in k8s and we are able to access the UI using port forwarding.
We want to expose it outside with specific domain and we have a GCP account how we can do it? what are the steps ? didnt find any useful link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to create an Ingress for external access, you can read all about that in the official [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

then you need to create a domain in your domain provider and link it to the external IP of the ingress you create earlier